# Windows 10 Shortcut to open new CMD Window

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Now I know we can create a keyboard shortcut for any shortcut. So in a similar way, I created a desktop shortcut for cmd, gave it the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut. So when I press that combination, it opens a new cmd window, now when minimized, if I press the same combination, it opens the same window.

How should I modify so that this shortcut opens up a new CMD (Just like terminal in Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I know, you can not open up multiple cmd prompt using this method. One alternative way would be to use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).
For the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut:

```
^!t::
Run %comspec% /k
return
```

[`comspec`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#ComSpec) is resolved to `cmd.exe` when using AutoHotkey.

---

A method that requires a couple of more keystrokes, but has the advantage of not requiring any program:

- <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Input `cmd`.
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>

A slightly shorter one:

- <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- <kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: You can also use WinKey+X and then press C.

Comment: @TomerGodinger Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dont. Just hold <kbd>shift</kbd>. job done.

**Reason**:

Holding shift opens a second-copy of the app. You can use the below on almost any Windows PC, not just your customised PC. This also works when clicking apps in the GUI.

> Generic method for all Win10 apps:

1. (optional) Pin your apps to the taskbar. Start with common apps (ie CMD) to the left.
2. <kbd>⊞Win</kbd>+<kbd>[number]</kbd> Open the corresponding app on taskbar (numbered from left>right).
3. Hold <kbd>shift</kbd> when opening apps to open a second one.

> **TLDR:** Windows 10 has shortcuts to `CMD`/`PowerShell` via  **power-user** menu

<kbd>⊞Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to open the power-user menu.

Tap the corresponding keyboard shortcut for CMD / PS.

---

**More Background info:**

The Power-User menu will now default to "Windows PowerShell" when you open it and tap <kbd>a</kbd> for `admin` or <kbd>i</kbd> for `Windows PowerShell` ... but [you *can* set it back](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/add-control-panel-and-command-prompt-winx-menu-windows-10) to <kbd>c</kbd> for `CMD` instead of powershell if needed.

*(but I will put a reason to leave it as PowerShell instead of CMD in comments)*

Comment: PowerShell has shortcuts to use most CMD commands now, but if you need to break-out into a command-prompt again, just type `CMD` to turn PowerShell back into a Command-Prompt.